# Java File I/O, how to change the selected directory?

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception

This is a concept of what I think would work, but for some reason every time I run this code I get a `NullPointerException` at the code:

```
for(String s : namesOfDirectoryFiles){
```

#### Code

```
public class poc {
    private File current;
    private File last;
    private String[] namesOfDirectoryFiles;
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        poc p = new poc();
        p.open("C:/");
        p.open(input.nextLine());
    }

    private void open(String name){
        current = new File(last, name);
        namesOfDirectoryFiles = current.list();
        for(String s : namesOfDirectoryFiles){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the exception occur before or after the first `p.open`?

Comment: never mind i figured out that i had not put

Comment: p.open("C:/");
     last = current;
     p.open(input.nextLine());
 }

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: Ya I'm sorry, I'm new to this site.

Comment: @user1644969: It is always a good idea to check user's input. You can still get a `NPE` if the user provides you with a bad input (i.e. invalid directory name). My answer suggests using `isDirectory()` to check for such bad input, you might consider this for your code :)

Comment: Ya, ive put in a file filter. That was only a basic one so you could get the basic idea

Answer (score 1):

This will occur if the abstract path does not exist.

Basically, if you try and list a directory that Java can not resolve to a physical location, it will return a null list

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)

> Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or
>   if an I/O error occurs

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [`isDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) method to check whether your file is actually a directory before proceeding with your logic. According to Javadoc, this method returns

> true if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists
>   and is a directory; false otherwise

You can modify your code to something like this:

```
private void open(String name){
    if(name != null){
        current = new File(last, name);

        if(current.isDirectory()){
            namesOfDirectoryFiles = current.list();
            for(String s : namesOfDirectoryFiles){
             System.out.println(s);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```